# attr(stroke-linecap) does nothing

Tags: raphael

```
var view = Raphael(10, 50, 800, 600); 
var testLine = view.path("M343,56 L343,560 Z");  // A simple straight line.
testLine.attr({stroke:"gold"}); 
testLine.attr({"stroke-width":25.0});
testLine.attr({"stroke-linecap":"round"});  // No linecap!
```

Why isn't linecap set to round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by removing the 'Z' path terminator:

```
var testLine = view.path("M343,56 L343,560");
```